# Azure DevOps restore packages from multiple sources on build pipeline

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, azure-devops, yaml, build-pipeline

Today, I was trying to fix the build pipeline from multiple sources on NuGet restore stage and had trouble finding the right settings to use.

I have packages in three different sources,

1. Public Nuget
2. Private Azure DevOps artifacts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have one private repo to add to your NuGet restore then its easy,

Your YAML should look something like this

[image]

To add the second task, keep the mouse focus on the next line to `- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1` and on the right-hand pane search for NuGet and choose the Articat you want to add

[image]

If you have more than one private source to restore, the best way is to restore the packages from `nuget.config` file.

first, add a nuget.config file on the root directory of the source control.

Add your nuget package sources as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="AAA" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/XXX/Prototypes/_packaging/YYY/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="BBB" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/XX/IdentityServer/_packaging/YYY/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

and now on your YAML add the below code.

```
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**\*.sln'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'
```

Your build pipeline should start working. Comment if there are any errors.

Comment: This was very helpful and easy to following. Thanks for sharing!